# Different scaling for two different fonts with fontspec

Tags: fonts, fontspec, fontsize, polyglossia

I am using FONT A for normal face, but use FONT B when I need to print something in bold face.

The problem is that the scaling of FONT A and FONT B is not the same. So, what I want to do is change the `Scale=` parameter for one of them, in order to get a nicer looking output.

But I don't know how to use this parameter when working with two different fonts.

Note: the document language is Hebrew, handled with polyglossia.

The usage of `Scale` is something like this:

```
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Times New Roman}[Script=Hebrew,Scale=1.5]
```

What I have done until now is

```latex
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Times New Roman}[
  Script=Hebrew,
  BoldFont=Arial-Bold]
```

I guess that the answer for that is to make use of the command

```latex
 \newfontface⟨cmd⟩{⟨font⟩}[⟨font features⟩]
```

decsribed in section 4 of the fontspec manual. But I don't know what is the polyglossia command of "Hebrew serif font in bold" that I need to pass to `\newfontface`, and what is the polyglossia command for "Hebrew serif font normal" to be passed in a similar way to an additional `\newfontface`.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Times New Roman}[
  Script=Latin,Language=English,
  BoldFont=Arial-Bold]
% Hebrew font selection:
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Times New Roman}[
  Script=Hebrew,
  BoldFont=Arial-Bold]
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
אבג \textbf{דהו} זחט
\textenglish{abcd \textbf{efg}.} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're after is setting the option `BoldFeatures` which allows you to apply specific options only to the bold face of a font:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\englishfont{Times New Roman}[
  Script=Latin,Language=English,
  BoldFont=Arial-Bold,
  BoldFeatures={Scale=1.5}]
% Hebrew font selection:
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Times New Roman}[
  Script=Hebrew,
  BoldFont=Arial-Bold,
  BoldFeatures={Scale=1.5}]
  
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\begin{document}

אבג \textbf{דהו} זחט
\textenglish{abcd \textbf{efg}.} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Similarly, you can set `UprightFeatures`, `ItalicFeatures` and `BoldItalicFeatures`.

For the `Scale` option, the values `MatchLowercase` and `MatchUppercase`  can help to scale the different fonts so that the height of the lowercase or uppercase letters matches.

---

I don't think that you really need to create a `\newfontface`, but you could use it for example as follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Times New Roman}[
  Script=Hebrew]
  
\newfontface\hebrewtextbf{Arial-Bold}[%
  Script=Hebrew,
  BoldFeatures={Scale=MatchUppercase}]
  
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\begin{document}

אבג {\hebrewtextbf דהו} זחט

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much. I think I would take this solution, but I am still curious to know: Is there a way to do it with `\newfontface`?

Comment: @tush See the edit, but I don't think you really need it. With the other approach, the fonts will be selected automatically and you can use the regular `textbf` macro.

Comment: I have uploaded [a related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/680241/), if you could please have a look.